# make outlook use restricted view on spam messages also after moving to deleted items folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

i'm using outlook 16.0 as part of the microsoft 365 subscription.
currently i'm on version 2210.

spam messages are moved to the "junk email" folder.
those messages are getting displayed in some "protected" or "restricted" view: rendered as text-only, hyperlinks disabled, etc.
all good.

when *deleting* such spam messages, they are moved to the "deleted items" folder.
but now they are no longer displayed in that restricted view.

**question:**
is there any way to make outlook retain that restricted view also after moving to deleted items?

bonus question:
is there any way to configure outlook to do the following: when deleting an item from the folder "junk email": immediately delete it permanently (instead of moving it to the folder "deleted items").

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to make outlook retain that restricted view also after moving to deleted items?

Unfortunately, moving junk mail to the deleted folder does not keep it in restricted view.

> is there any way to configure outlook to do the following: when deleting an item from the folder "junk email": immediately delete it permanently (instead of moving it to the folder "deleted items").

It's suggested that you could create a quick step:

[image]

In this way, when you want to permanently delete the Junk email, you just need to select and click the quick steps.